# Finding 'conditional probability'

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, arithmetic

Q-) The number of injury claims per month is modelled by a random variable N with:
                 P(N=n)= 1/(n+1)(n+2),where n>=0
Determine the probability of *at least 1 claim during a particular month, GIVEN that there have been at most 4 claims during that month*

A-) I tried punching in values of n.
So I got the conditional probability as =
   (I/6 +1/12+ 1/20+ 1/30)/(1/3 + 1/6 + 1/12 + 1/20 + 1/30) 
But this isn't matching with the given answer. I am not sure what's wrong. If at all it is wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'self-study' questions, if this is one, must have the tag saying `self-study`. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: (Welcome to the site!) It would be also helpful to give a more detailed explanation of what you tried (which conditional probability you are evaluating, where do the numbers come from etc.) as well as the final answer vs. the given answer.  While you edit the tag and the answer, please also change the tag condition-number (presumably you meant conditional probability, condition numbers are something different)

Comment: Where did "1/3" come from in the denominator?

Comment: Oh yes..my bad I will keep that in mind @juho kokkala

Comment: 1/3 is the value when n=0,@whuber

Comment: No I made a mistake ...

Comment: N=0 ..will be 1/2 ..I wrote it 1/3

Comment: My answer matches now..2/5. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$$
P(N=n) = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$

$$
P(N \neq 0 | N \leq 4) = 1 - P(N=0 | N \leq 4) = 1- \frac{P(N = 0) \cdot P(N \leq4)}{P(N \leq 4)}
$$

$$
P(N \leq 4) = P(N=0, 1, 2, 3, 4) \\
= P(N=0) + P(N=1) + P(N=2) + P(N=3) + P(N=4) \\
$$

You can now solve the rest by yourself, since you know the formula for $P(N=n)$.

Comment: In the second line you appear to assume the events $N=0$ and $N\le 4$ are independent, but obviously that's not the case.

Comment: I apologize, I have not looked at this material in quite a long time.  Please offer your advice, I would genuinely be interested in knowing how you would approach the question.

Comment: I would apply the formula for conditional probability directly, much as in the question itself.  To simplify the answer I would first work out the CDF, which has a very simple form.

Comment: Thank you guys.I figured out my mistake. Wrong value of n=0.

Comment: But @whuber why do you think it will be a good idea find cdf here? It's a discrete random variable. I will have eventually have to work out and add all the values(and x>=0). Or is there a way to find a generalized cdf for a discrete random variable ?

Comment: *Every* random variable has a CDF.  In this case, it takes on a particularly simple form.  By doing that calculation at the outset, you likely would not have made the mistake you did.

Comment: But how would I find the cdf, as in, I have not quite understood how am I supposed to make use of your suggestion. I will have to find the cumulative probability for many values of X. Or you mean I should just first right down the cumulative probabilities till 4? Or can I
 use f(x) to find a generalized cumulative probability function for atleast this particular discrete random variable.